# has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a message board. A `User` can create a new `Discussion`.  A `User` can also create a new `Post` to a `Discussion`.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :discussions 
has_many :replies, through: :discussions, source: :posts
```

So a `Discussion` has many `Posts` belonging to many different `Users`.
On my `show` page I want to display all the `Posts` and their corresponding `Users`.  I know I can get a `User's` posts with `user.replies`. But I can't figure out how to do the opposite: get the `User` if I have the `Post`?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="discussion_right">
    <div class="discussion_head">
      <% t = post.created_at %>
      <%= t.strftime("Posted on %b %-d, %Y %l:%M %P") %>
    </div>
    <div class="discussion_body">
      <%= post.body %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="discussion_left">
    <div class="discussion_head">
      <%= post.user.first_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**discussion.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
```

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :discussion
```

obviously the line `post.user.first_name` doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a user can create a post, then you need to add a `user_id` to posts and add a `belongs_to` relationship

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:references
rake db:migrate

# post.rb
belongs_to :user
```

then you should be able to query for `post.user`

Comment: Here's how I create a new post: `@discussion = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])` but this only sets the discussion_id of the post and not the user_id of the post.  How can I have both of them be set? (I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts` to set the Post values)

Comment: you have to manually pass the `user_id` to the post hash or add a `hidden_field` for the `user_id` in the view.

Comment: If `has_many :through` gives me posts for each user with the user.replies syntax I feel like there has to be a connection from each post back to their user.

Comment: your `replies` association is kinda wrong. suppose you have a discussion, then 2 users posted on that discussion. user.replies will give you a list of all post for all discussions created by that user, not only replies created by user.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to manually add user_id to the post hash?

Comment: i think you can just do `@discussion.posts.first.user_id = current_user.id` when creating a discussion